# How to type unique letters only in input text box in html or react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to create an input box that allows to type only a distinct alphabet letter in the input box
( No duplicate alphabet value, ONLY ONE)

I looked up all the attributes for input box but I couldn't find one and there were no example.

Do I have to handle it within JavaScript functions?
(I am using React)

```
<input
            className="App-Contain-Input"
            name="containedLetter"
            type={"text"}
            onChange={containedChange}
          />
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what didn't you like about my solution?

Comment: I only ask because most of these solutions make one or both of two assumptions: 

1. The user will only edit from the end of the input, and will never edit from the beginning or middle.
2. What happens if the user does a copy/paste? At that point, any keyboard focused or last character solution becomes irrelevant.

In general, it seems best to try to be completely input device agnostic and deal with the inputted value as a value, regardless of how it got there.

Comment: Oh, I really wish I could accept all of the answers, and leave a thank you comment. But it's my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow, and they said officially not to say "thank you" or to comment without any purpose of technicals.. I really loved your question since it was very simple too, and I just accepted any question that was the most recent. Sorry if you felt that way, I also wanted to upvote too but I don't have 15 reputations so couldn't give anyone. @JohnDetlefs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do it with a cheeky two-liner is to get rid of any non-letters with regex, then let Set do the de-duping by converting to Array => Set => Array => String:

As a side note, many of the other solutions posted here make one or both of two assumptions:

1. The user is only ever going to edit the last character... but what if they edit from the beginning or middle? Any last character solution will then fail.
2. The user will never copy/paste a complete value... again, if they do, most of these solutions will fail.

In general, it's best to be completely agnostic as to *how* the value is going to arrive to the input, and simply deal with the value after it has arrived.

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type='text'
                value={value}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    const onlyLetters = e.target.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');
                    setValue(Array.from(new Set(onlyLetters.split(''))).join(''));
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Is there any way that the users doesn't have to type twice if they modify the input box in the middle or somewhere not at the end of the letters?

Comment: Apologies, not sure what you mean by that question? Also, ta for marking my answer as correct! 

Comment: Oh never mind, my own code was the problem. Thanks!
+ you were right that your solution was the answer where I could modify the letters in the beginning or in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how this can be done, note that we have to use `onkeydown` which fires when a key is being pressed, but not before it is being released (this way we can intercept and prevent the key stroke from being taken into account):

```
function MyInput() {

  const containedChange = (event) => {
    if (event.key.length === 1 && event.code.startsWith('Key') && event.code.length === 4 && event.target.value.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      event.preventDefault()
      return false;
    }
    
    return true
  }
          
          
  return (
    <input
      id="input"
      className="App-Contain-Input"
      name="containedLetter"
      type="text"
      onkeydown={containedChange}
    />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a state to maintain the current value of the input. Then when the value changes get the last letter of the input, check that it's a letter, and if it is a letter and it isn't already in the state, update the state with the new input value.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ input, setInput ] = useState('');

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const lastChar = value.slice(-1);
    const isLetter = /[a-zA-Z]/.test(lastChar);
    if (isLetter && !input.includes(lastChar)) {
      setInput(value);
    }
  }

  function handleKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.code === 'Backspace') {
      setInput(input.slice(0, input.length - 1));
    }
  }

  return (
    <input
      value={input}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
    />
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Small issue when using backspace.

Comment: Ah, that's a feature not a bug :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am fresh to React so was wondering what's the reason the function couldn't handle backspace for deleting without having handleKeyDown function?

Comment: In this example it's because I'm checking the last character in value, and only if its not in the state, update the state. So because the input uses the state as the value backspace has no effect when you use it because the condition will always be `true`. There maybe a better way of achieving this obviously. @ProgrammingPlayer

Answer (score 0):

An `isogram` is a word with no repeating letters. You can check this using `regex`

```
function isIsogram (str) {
    return !/(.).*\1/.test(str);
}
```

Or using [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
function isIsogram(str) {
    var strArray = str.split("");
     return !strArray.some(function(el,idx,arr){
       return arr.lastIndexOf(el)!=idx;
     });
}
```

In `react` - you need to use state to reject inputs which contain repeated letters (not an `Isogram`). Complete example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-morning-606mzu?file=/src/App.js).

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [ text, setText ] = useState('');

  function isIsogram(str) {
    var strArray = str.split("");
     return !strArray.some(function(el,idx,arr){
       return arr.lastIndexOf(el)!==idx;
     });
}

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    console.log(isIsogram(value));
    if (value.length === 1 || isIsogram(value)) {
      setText(value);
    }
  }

  return (
    <input value={text} onChange={handleChange} />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `containedChange` function can be like this:

```
const containedChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const lastChar = value[value.length - 1];

    if (value.slice(value.length - 1, value.length).indexOf(lastChar) != -1) {
        // show error message
    }
```

The function checks whether the last entered character already exists in the previous value or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what would be the reason we use 'indexOf()' instead of 'contains()'?

Comment: Did you mean `includes()`? AFAIK, there's no `contains()` method for string.
And, there's no specific reason to use `indexOf()`. I just thought it would be easier for you to understand if I use this in the example.

Answer (score 0):

One pure js solution would be to handle the input value in onkeyup event where we have access to the latest key as well as updated input target value.

If the latest key pressed is duplicate then we will found it on 2 location in the target value, first on some where middle of the target value and second at the end of the target value. So we can remove the value at the end (which is the duplicate one).

The below code snippet shows the implementation of above in React

```
const Input = () => {
  const handleKeyUp = (e) => {
    const { key, target: { value }} = e;
    const len = value.length;

    if (value.indexOf(key) < len - 2) {
        e.target.value = value.slice(0, len - 1);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Unique Keywords</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="my-input" onKeyUp={handleKeyUp} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Btw, this
if (value.indexOf(key) < len - 2) {
        e.target.value = value.slice(0, len - 1);
    }
if I change that -2 to -1 it works as I expected. However, I don't know how react works, but when I spam input box, it allows me to have duplicate words.. lol